# Loop json using Mustache

Tags: javascript, json, mustache

I've got this :

```
  field: [
      { text: 'text 1' },
      { price1: '10' },
      { price2: '16' },
      { text: 'text2' },
      { price1: '20' },
      { price2: '23' }
    ];
```

and I want to repeat data with mustache, I've tried it with :

```
{{#field}}
      <span>{{text}}</span>
{{/field}}
```

but it doesn't work, can anyone help?

Comment: is your `field` a JSON or a string of JSON,it looks like a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when iterating through a JSON in moustache you do as follows

```
{{#each field}}
    <span> {{ text }} </span>
{{/each}}
```

by the way your JSON is not properly rendered, i think each JSON Objcet had to look like so

```
field: [
    { 
        text: 'text 1,
        price1: '10',
        price2: '16'
    },
    { 
        text: 'text2',
        price1: '20',
        price2: '23'
    },
];
```

That way you get to access all the elements in an Object